# Alternative of Query String to pass data from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, http-get

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5. I just want to know if there is any alternative of Query String to pass data from view to controller? Because The data I want to pass affect multiple pages where I can't use query strings.
I know following. but is there any other better way exists ?

1. Using Session
2. Using ViewData/ViewBag/TempData
3. Using Class Object.

In my project, There is a checkbox on layout page. Which value is accessible on more than 5-6 pages. So If any user check it and click on some link; based on checkbox value, user is allowed to open that with specific functionality. If checkbox is not checked he don't have access to special functionalities. Currently I am doing it through query string but now I want another approach. My TL don't want me to use Session. And ViewData/ViewBag/TempData is of no use to me. And Object is not of my use.

Comment: Is it passing data from client side or from server side?

Comment: u can use hidden fields in ur form to post data from view to controller...

Comment: @RAJ It is passing from client side

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla so do i have to take page as http-post?

Comment: yeah...because this is only option left with u...becoz u dont want to use session and all other things...

Comment: I dont know what u want exactly. But, if you want parameter value from view to controller than you have another option like Model Binding.

Comment: Yes thats Agree with Shell thats why I asked where is he want to pass data, he can pass json object or use @Ajax.BeginFrom something and all fields of form will be passed as model

Comment: @Dhwani would you please add what is the context and what you want to achive

Comment: @RAJ I have modified my question.

Comment: Using Jquery, create a cookie and write the value of the checkbox whenever the user changes it's value. When you navigate to a different page and the controller's event is loaded, load the cookie's value server side.

Comment: @FredFrancisco what happen when cookies are disabled for browser?

Comment: @FredFrancisco can u show some example?

Comment: @Shell well the cookie approach isn't an option then. Another solution is to create a webmethod that is called using ajax on the change event of the checkbox, that would pass along the checkbox value. Webmethod saves the value in the database and later retrieved in the controller.

Comment: @Dhwani here's a plugin for managing cookies via jquery: www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery. Create a cookie in the client side on the .change event of the checkbox. Now, do a request on the server side:   var chkboxVal = Response.Cookies["valueOfCheckBox"].ToString()

Comment: @FredFrancisco then it is better to use ViewBag instead of database.